# If we don't know anything for certain, how do we know that?

Tags: epistemology, knowledge, skepticism

I think it is the case that we don't know anything for certain. But if that is the case, how can we know that we don't know anything for certain? This is related to Socrates's famous remark that all he knows is that he knows nothing for certain. But maybe we can't even know if we know nothing.

Comment: We don't know that "for certain" either, but we are pretty sure. As with everything else, "knowing for certain" is a useless expression when taken literally. Only omniscient God knows anything "for certain".

Comment: What if we just quasi-know, for certain, that we don't know, for certain? And you might ask, "How do we know that we quasi-know?" but then we could reply, "Ah, but we don't, we quasi-know that we quasi-know," and proceed apace.

Comment: If I remember Sextus Empiricus correctly in Pyrrhonian Skepticism we do not claim to know this but we have observed that we can always produce isosthenia (two opposing arguments of the same strength) and we will do so if we ever have to counter our belief in certainty

Comment: If you are imagining that there is some sort of distinction between "knowing" and "knowing for certain" (this seems to be strongly suggested by the way you phrase your question), then there is no contradiction in saying "I know that I don't know anything for certain". There would only be a contradiction in saying "I know for certain that I don't know anything for certain".

Comment: @Conifold:  You're too pessimistic.  Can't you know for certain whether you exist?  I mean, what's the point of your comment, if not?

Comment: @Marxos I do not know "for certain" that it has a point, but there it is - me being optimistic. Since "certainty" is a useless standard it would be unwise to base what we do on it as well. That is what practical certainty is for, or even less than that.

Comment: @Conifold:  Well, the problem seems to be in your use of the word "if".  Stop at that point, and see if you're actually certain or not before you ask it.

Comment: @Marxos The problem is in your vague use of "certain", you do not seem to distinguish between common sense certainty sufficient for action and "absolute" certainty in the OP that we cannot achieve.

Comment: @Conifold:  The so-called common-sense "certainty" to which you refer, is simply called "belief".

Comment: @Marxos Nope. Even common talk distinguishes "I believe that X" from "I am sure that X", but even "I am sure" does not attach "absolute certainty".

Comment: @Conifold:  Okay, troll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I  think part of this is what we mean by know. If we take knowledge as justified true belief (i.e., must be the result of true premises and an inference method), then you need to be rational to know anything; this rules out most, if not all other species from knowing anything.

However, I'll take the foundationalist view that there are some unjustifiable true facts upon which we can reason from.

Specifically, we know one at least one thing for certain - *we are* (ala Descartes). It is a brute fact that is immediately known and irrefutable. You cannot be fooled into thinking you exist, nor can we say it is an illusion, if only because an illusion (or any experience) needs a subject and therefore if there is an experience there is the subject having that experience, by necessity.

This is well summarized by James Pryor in “There is Immediate Justification”, in Turri, Steup, & Sosa (eds.) Contemporary Debates in Epistemology. 2nd Edition, Blackwell (2013)

> I believe that I feel tired, that I have a headache, that I intend to
> get a glass of water, that black is not white; and in each case, it
> doesn’t seem that my justification is mediated by any other
> proposition. This supports the claim that there are foundational
> beliefs, though it does not speak directly to the thesis that all
> other beliefs must depend, ultimately, on foundational beliefs for
> their justification.

*(Source: Hasan, Ali and Richard Fumerton, "Foundationalist Theories of Epistemic Justification", The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (Fall 2022 Edition), Edward N. Zalta & Uri Nodelman (eds.), URL = https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/fall2022/entries/justep-foundational/)*

People confuse this basic fact with more nuanced positions that make claims beyond the necessary experience-experiencer pairing, which is where we get into Reliabilism, content externalism, etc which move from just "I am a subject" to trying to interpret the world beyond our minds.

Comment: I’m a bit sceptical that the “cogito” is a tough argument in the light of current philosophy of mind taking into account also neuroscience. Because even introspection leads only to the content of our self-model. The latter is a brain construct as the result of much internal processing. Its function is to provide an aggregated and consistent view of all stimuli and perceptions. The self-model is embedded into the world-model. (1/2)

Comment: We know from mental disturbances that both models may have faults – an analogue of the malevolent demon of Descartes, but in the absence of God. - The self-model theory is due to Th. Metzinger and is under discussion like the Integrated Information Theory is. One key feature: Both models are transparent. But we cannot experience that they are models while pretending direct access to the world. (2/2)

Comment: @JoWehler can you dumb down you comments for me ;-) I'm having a hard time grasping what you are getting at. I am not arguing for the reality of an eternal self or homunculus, if that is what you are getting at. A subjective experience is, necessarily, aware of itself, right? That awareness is direct, unmediated knowledge of having that experience. I'm not saying that knowledge tells us anything further (e.g., we have a soul, there is an outside world that looks like it appears to me). What I was getting at above is we are certain of the contents of our self-model.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. – I agree with the first part of your comment, up to the question mark. – I am sceptical about the attribute “direct” in the second part. My point is that even our self-model can fail. Each software has faults, also the self-model may have faults or may become faulty. Then our self-model fools us, producing mental disturbances up to ego disorder and several forms of psychosis. - Concerning the self-model theory see "Thomas Metzinger: Being No One". For me it is a very challenging book, even when reading his many popularizations  first. It is a heavyweight like IIT.

Comment: @JoWehler gotcha, What is meant by " self-model may have faults or may become faulty" what is the thing that it is failing to do?

Comment: "What is the thing that it is failing to do?" The self-model of a person with a mental disorder fails to process the input stimuli in a way which allows the person to orientate oneself and to act like nearly all other humans do in the same environment. (I do not touch on the problem how to define a norm.) – Please let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @JoWehler - I think you took my use of "direct' to mean we directly experience sensory information/external knowledge. My post was actually skeptical of that - what I am saying is that even the mentally disordered can't  help but accurately experience their self-model, however disordered it is vis-a-vis the outside world.

I am saying that we cannot incorrectly experience an experience, but that experience can definitely be misleading or misinterpreted relative to the outside world.

Comment: Maybe you're using the royal "we", but it should still be noted that the cogito is about "I", not "we" - "I am". And what comes before is "I think therefore", which seems to make "I am" the conclusion, in which case it wouldn't be a "brute fact". "I think" doesn't seem like much of a "brute fact" either, as that's inferred from the experience of thinking. I have not found a need to appeal to "brute facts", and those I most commonly hear referring to that idea try to use it to smuggle in a presupposition that their god exists. To call all mental states "foundational beliefs" seems dire indeed.

Comment: @NotThatGuy that is the core tenet expressed above in the quote re: foundationalism. They are foundational only in the sense that they are necessarily known to the experiencer, but they may be very bad basis for some interence (again, the quite I put in there sums it up nicely)

Comment: Annika -- Endorsing Jo Wehler here.  The point made by the pretty extensive and interesting data cited by the delusionists is that we can very often be confused about whether we are having an experience or not, as well as its content.  The inference by the Delusionists that selfhood therefore does not exist, is a leap WAY beyond that data.  But their data very effectively challenges "That awareness is direct, unmediated knowledge of having that experience."   Awareness and experience also appear to be constructs, at least partially.

Comment: @Dcleve - then when we  have a subjective experience, what is that? What is being confused? And confused in what sense? Basically all I am saying is that we know there is subjective awareness because the only thing we have to go on is that awareness. However, I'm saying nothing of its veracity wrt anything else -- unless you are denying that subjectivity/consciousness even exists. Whatever we call it there are undeniably experience and I'd be very skeptical of someone who is effectively claiming they are a confused zombie.

Comment: @Annika -- Experience IS the foundation to everything we know.  But Foundationalism is -- not valid, as nothing we know is indisputable.   We are often wrong about our own experiences, read Blackmore's A Very Short Introduction to Consciousness:    https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1C1TJFIWBZ8ZQ?ref=pf_ov_at_pdctrvw_srp Our introspection is validly revealing SOMETHING, but it is not 100% trustworthy -- far from it.  Our logic categories just don't seem to work very well for experience.

Comment: @Dcleve I'm not sure Foundationalism has been resoundingly refuted, but the contents of an experience are not disputable -- if the experience is one of seeing red, it is the experience of seeing red. Now, eliminative materialists will say, no you are just think you are seeing red (whatever that means) - to which one can say, fine, I am experiencing the thought of experiencing red. To deny that experience exists makes no sense, because if we know anything, we know we are not zombies because zombies are incapable of any experience.

Comment: @Dcleve basically, the illusion/reality gap seems to collapse when it comes to our inner experiences -- to quote Searle  “where consciousness is concerned the existence of the appearance is the reality”

Comment: @Dcleve what I do agree with is that anything beyond the conscious experience is theory laden/interpretive. And, in fact, our conscious experiences are shaped by theories, but nonetheless, the experiences presented are what they are. If I hallucinate and see a floating orb in front of me, I am having that experience -- I'm also having mental issues lol but it makes no sense to say the experience itself doesn't exist as an experience.

Comment: @Annika -- the best of the delusionists is David Eagleman.  In Incognito he spells out how our brain creates the illusion of a "Theater of the Mind" which our conscious awareness INcorrectly thinks is fully populated with qualia.  SOME of what is passed across this interface is actual perceptual qualia.  MOST of it is logical qualia like "something is over here" or "don't pay attention to this area".  Our conscious mind infers a populated Cartesian theater, having been collaboratively tricked to do so by a stage magician.

Comment: @Dcleve I agree with all that, but I think you are addressing something that I didn't intend to convey in my answer.  You mention that our brain "creates the illusion of a "Theater of the Mind"". But we have direct knowledge of this illusion, that is what I'm getting at - there is no gap between the experience of that illusion and the reality of that illusion because they are literally the same thing. That is all I was getting at as far as what we can know "for certain" - we can't not know that we are conscious of a conscious experience (illusion or otherwise)

Comment: Annika -- The Delusionists show that no, we are at times confused about what we experience.  The confabulations by test subjects show that we mislead OURSELVES about our own thoughts and experiences.  Take an example of driving -- do we experience QUALIA of every stoplight or stop sign? Very unlikely -- system 1 is lazy, and if system 2 does not probe, then almost all info passed will be by logic categories.  But if asked -- we will then confabulate qualia into our memory.

Comment: @Dcleve that is an issue of memory and perception and our ability to confabulate what we experience. But the fact that I know I am experiencing is certain. Like I've been trying to say, anything beyond knowing that we are having experiences (internal, external, drug induced, recalling false memories) is subject to fallibilism

Comment: Annika - If one is confabulating what one experiences, then one can confabulate THAT we experience too.  Driving without qualia appears, from my own and other's memories, to be pretty common.  But all of us tend to confabulate when asked about what happened when we drove.

Comment: @Dcleve so we can confabulate that we are confabulating? Are you making an argument that we are confused zombies? I think we are either taking past one another or you are arguing for the absence of experience/subjectivity in which case I don’t buy the arguments from eliminative theories of mind. If I am wrong in both counts then happy to either read a suggested reference or move this to chat.

Comment: Chat room created:  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149556/discussion-on-qualia-and-reliability-of-perception-of-experience

Answer (score 5):

If I remember right, Socrates did not say "I know that I know nothing", but "I do not believe to know what I do not know (Apology 21 d7 )".

I understand the latter statement as follows: I know that also I myself do not know the answer to the far reaching questions which I ask to the experts. The experts, who being experts on their field, believe to know also the right answers on many more other fields.

Comment: "I seem, then, in just this little thing to be wiser than this man at any rate, that what I do not know I do not think I know either."

-Socrates, in Plato's 'Apology'