# All I know is that I know nothing. Does this statement of Socrates still resonate in modern philosophy?

Tags: knowledge, socrates, nothing, wisdom, humility

Regardless of attribution, this could be interpreted as profound wisdom or a suggestion that things are ultimately unknowable. It certainly seems to indicate humility. Does any of this still hold true now?

Comment: Socrates does not say this, please see the correct quote in my answer to this previous question https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/104334/if-we-dont-know-anything-for-certain-how-do-we-know-that/104344#104344

Comment: Thanks. There is debate about the exact phrasing. He is quoted by Plato. I did begin with "Regardless of attribution,...". So, the question is about the sentiment expressed.

Comment: Concerning humility and the borders of our knowledge you may take the following quote ascribed to Newton "I do not know what I may appear to the world, but to myself I seem to have been only like a boy playing on the seashore, and diverting myself in now and then finding a smoother pebble or a prettier shell than ordinary, whilst the great ocean of truth lay all undiscovered before me."

Comment: This is an inspirational quote.

Comment: My translation from the apology (Plato 21d) : "So, it seems to me that I am a little wiser than him, at least me, I do not think that I know the things that I do not"

Comment: Thanks. I am reminded of the Dunning-Kruger Effect. A wise man knows the limits of his own knowledge, is how I interpret the quotation from Socrates.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different interpretations regarding how this phrase ended up both in Western and Greek literature, both in ancient and more modern times. Without going into historical details, let's see what is really important about it.

Socrates used a method called dialectic in Western philosophy, but in Greek is mainly called "μαιευτική" from "μαία" which is the woman that helps other women to bring birth to a child.

It's obvious that Plato used this word in order to describe the process that Socrates used to get the truth out of another person.

**Many times though, this method resulted in a dialectic dead-end for the other person, so the person's ignorance about the subject was revealed.**

The phrase you are talking about speaks about this situation; it's a phrase that survived as a designation of his method.